# Guess the kingdom from the hints

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> It has one ruler who all the subjects serve.
>   The kingdom has numerous institutions setup by the subjects for the benefit of the ruler.
>   For some reason, the sewers of the kingdom are free of rats.
>   The ruler has a very few ministers who directly report to him.
>   There is no punishment for treason. At times the ruler provokes the subjects to attempt it.
>   The kingdom has efficient roads and developed vehicles.
>   It has a distinct automatic watering system which helps it grow grass.

Guess the kingdom and explain the hints.

Comment: I assume the sewers are free of rats instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit iffy on a couple of the lines, but it sounds like

> a human body.

*It has one ruler who all the subjects serve.*

> brain

*The kingdom has numerous institutions setup by the subjects for the benefit of the ruler*

> organs

*For some reason, the sewers of the kingdom are free of rats*

> digestive system

*The ruler has a very few ministers who directly report to him.*

> five senses

*There is no punishment for treason. At times the ruler provokes the subjects to attempt it.*

> hmm, illness, I think?

The kingdom has efficient roads and developed vehicles.

> blood vessels and blood cells

It has a distinct automatic watering system which helps it grow grass.

> something to do with how hair grows on the skin?

Comment: Ruler - You or the conscious or whatever. Brain is a subject too. The sewers  are the intestines. Ministers are the voluntary parts which you can control like hands, legs etc. Subjects are the cells in the body. If the ruler does something injurious to health he is losing control of the body by damaging it. It is been taken away from him.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the kingdom is:

> a school

It has one ruler who all the subjects serve.

> the principal, head master, etc.

The kingdom has numerous institutions setup by the subjects for the benefit of the ruler.

> subjects are students, institutions are extra-curricular activites. the "ruler" benefits from student participation and learning (the school gets more money)

For some reason, the sewers of the kingdom are free or rats.

> modern day plumbing does not have rats

The ruler has a very ministers who directly report to him.
There is no punishment for treason. At times the ruler provokes the subjects to attempt it.

> the teachers are the ministers. students are encouraged to ask questions and challenge everything

The kingdom has efficient roads and developed vehicles.

> roads are hallways. vehicles are desks

It has a distinct automatic watering system which helps it grow grass.

> watering fountains, the "grass" is students and "growing" is learning

Comment: Good one but not the right answer :)